# Swift 3 NSWindowStyleMask

Tags: nswindow

After update to Xcode 8 with Swift 3, the following code no longer work

```
self.view.window?.styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask
```

Please advise me on how can I fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
```

Or

```
window.styleMask = window.styleMask.union(.fullSizeContentView)
```

Example:

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    guard let window = window else { return }
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    window.titleVisibility = .hidden
    window.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)
}
```

[image: Empty Window Controller]

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```
    window.styleMask = [.titled, .miniaturizable]
```

Comment: This solution is both more readable and feels familiar to swift 2 syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone also having the same issue like I did, here are the working version for SWIFT 3

If using NSViewController, add the following: (Thanks to João Oliveira contribution)

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.titled) /* Enable Title */
    self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.closable)  /* Enable Close button */
}
```

If using NSWindowController, add the following:

```
init(){
   self.m_window = NSWindow(
   contentRect: NSRect(300, 300, width: 500, height: 500), 
   styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask(rawValue: (NSWindowStyleMask.closable.rawValue | NSWindowStyleMask.titled.rawValue)), 
   backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered, defer: false
   )
}
```

** Change the X, Y position and Width and Height to your preferred window size.